# Stack implementation with exceptions

Tags: java, stack

I would like to know if this is a great stack implementation. I created my own exception. Was that a bad idea or unnecessary? Should I have just thrown a IndexOutOfBounds exception instead of my own.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stack2{
    private int[] stack;
    private int size;

    public Stack2(){
        stack = new int[10];
        size = 0;
    }

    public Stack2(int height){
        if(height <= 0){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        stack = new int[height];
        size = 0;
    }

    public void add(int value){
        if (size == stack.length){
            throw new StackOverflowException();
        }
        stack[size] = value;
        size++;
    }


    public int pop(){
        if(size == 0){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        size--;
        return stack[size + 1];
    }

    public int peek(){
        if(size == 0){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        return stack[size - 1];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(size == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }

    class StackOverflowException extends RuntimeException{
        public StackOverflowException(){
            super("Nothing can be added to the stack. The stack was full and has overflowed");
        }

        public StackOverflowException(String message){
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this code for correctness? Why is there a `StackOverflowException` class that you never use? Would you like to post your `EmptyStackException` class?

Comment: I use the StackOverflowException class in the add method. EmptyStackException is a part of the java API.

Comment: It has been demonstrated in an answer, that this code does not behave as expected (`add(3);pop()` returns 0). As such I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is not working as intended. For more information, please see the [help/on-topic]. Thanks

Comment: No, it works. I fixed it.

Comment: @jillian we don't allow editing code after an answer has been given

Comment: oh, okay. I did not know that.

Comment: This question has been [mentioned on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6926/9357).

Comment: now that you have figured out what was broken, please feel free to post the correct, bug free, code as a new question.  [Please make sure to follow the guidelines of Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack returns `0` instead of `3` on this simple case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack2 s = new Stack2();
    s.add(3);
    System.out.println(s.pop());
}
```

Traditionally, the stack operations are called "push" and "pop".  It's unusual to have "add" and "pop".

The `isEmpty()` method would be better written as:

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return size == 0
}
```

Throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would be worse, since it would result in a "leaky" abstraction.  The user shouldn't know that the stack is actually backed by an array.